# How to undelegate a click false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, event-handling

How to undelegate this, and how to re-delegate (on/off)... Without affect the other event handlers in 'a'.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('document').delegate( 'a', 'click' function(){return false;} ); 
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/

Comment: -1 for not bothering to read the documentation.

Comment: this is for do questions, all questions can be solved using documentations, so what are stackoverflow???? I hate this people and this comments!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, I'm using the `click.myEvent` to create my own [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) within the click event, so this way it will only be `.myEvent` events that get generated and removed.

Deletate

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('document').delegate( 'a', 'click.myEvent', function(){return false;} ); 
});
```

Undelegate:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('document').undelegate( 'a', 'click.myEvent' ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With event delegation, if there's going to be regular switching on and off, easiest thing to do is to make the selector a class that you change when needed.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('document').delegate( 'a.clickable', 'click' function(){return false;} ); 
});
```

Just remove the `clickable` class to disable for an element, and add it back in to enable.

No need to repeatedly unbind/bind the delegate handler.